# Mod Rewrite redirect URL with query string to pretty url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I successfully changed my URLs from ugly ones with several parameters in the querystring to clean looking ones with the help of mod rewrite. However, there are many url's for my site. Rather than go back and edit the href attribute on each and every one of my anchor tags, I tried to write a redirect function in the .htaccess file that automatically redirects the old url to the new one.

In my .htaccess file, I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect teams.php?league=$1&team=$2&year=$3&tab=$4 teams/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(css|js|img)/
RewriteRule ^teams/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ teams.php?league=$1&team=$2&year=$3&tab=$4 [L]
```

No luck though... any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Am I right in saying you want anyone who clicks `teams.php?league=.*...` to show as `teams/$1/...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do a check that the old URL with the `php` in it *is actually being requested* by matching against `%{THE_REQUEST}`, otherwise it'll redirect loop forever (e.g. user goes to team.php, serve redirects to teams, browser requests teams, server rewrites as teams.php, server sees "teams.php" and redirects to teams, browser requests teams, server rewrites as teams.php, etc. etc.)

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect when the user actually requests for teams.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /teams\.php\?league=([^&]+)&team=([^&]+)&year=([^&]+)&tab=([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^teams\.php$ /teams/%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite any /teams/ URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(css|js|img)/
RewriteRule ^teams/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ teams.php?league=$1&team=$2&year=$3&tab=$4 [L]
```

Comment: Why exactly do we need !^(css|js|img)/ and if I use your syntax for redirecting many files like teams.php, should I copy/paste the RewriteCond !^(css|js|img) every time, or it is enough once in the htaccess. Thanks :)

Comment: The person who asked the question doesn't want to rewrite requests for the css, js, or img folders