# Redirect sub directory to diff domain using same subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

There are many posts on this issue, but I couldn't find the answer.
When I tried to change htaccess it caused problems.

www.xyz.com points to www.xyz.com/mysite 
This works great and user only sees www.xyz.com 
Unfortunately if someone types www.xyz.com/mysite they also get the same site, but they see www.xyz.com/mysite

Ideally when they type www.xyz.com/mysite it will show www.xyz.com.

Thank You for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod Rewrite redirect URL with query string to pretty url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629896/mod-rewrite-redirect-url-with-query-string-to-pretty-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule inside `/mysite/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mysite [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=302,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  This was not a htaccess issue.  It was a WordPress issue.  I did not change the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) in the General Settings to the new url.