# how can rewrite first rules and remove part of url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

can rewrite first rules ?

from

```
http://sitename.com/media/resizer/420x218/r/sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/image.jpg
```

to

```
http://sitename.com/media/resizer/420x218/r/2013/12/image.jpg
```

by removing `sitename.com/wp-content/uploads`

this my current htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /media/
RewriteRule ^resizer/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) resizer/resize.php?src=http://$3&h=$2&w=$1&zc=0&s=1
</IfModule>
```

i use this method : http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-timthumb-with-custom-urls-for-site-optimization--wp-23607

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course you can. Since you don't include part of the source url in the url anymore, you'll have to add it yourself in the rewritten part.

```
RewriteRule ^resizer/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) resizer/resize.php?src=http://sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/$3&h=$2&w=$1&zc=0&s=1
```

Comment: this need to edit src of image first to work thanks @Sumurai8

Comment: That's covered in the tag wiki of mod-rewrite: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info . See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629896/mod-rewrite-redirect-url-with-query-string-to-pretty-url) for more details.